# List files in Linux that don't contain a number in their name

Tags: linux, list

Could you help me out list files that do not contain any number?

I tried `ls *[!0-9]*` but it doesn't work.

I even tried `[!0-9]*[!0-9]` but it shows the file that contain a number in the middle of their name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: If you're using bash, take a look at the patterns enabled by the `extglob` option.

Comment: e.g. `ls !(*[0-9]*)`

Comment: Thank you! It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Use find:

```
find . -not -name '*[0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | grep -v '[0-9]'
```

Often times it is easier to get everything and then filter out the things you don't want.

If you care about files with weird characters, consider using `ls -b`

Comment: This will break for filenames that contain newlines. Do not parse the output of `ls`. It is designed for humans, not tools. That's what `find` is for.

Comment: thank you, it worked.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Actually, this will work find for files with newlines in the name, as `ls` will print the newlines as `?` by default (since otherwise they are too confusing).  For more general weird file name handling, you can use the `-b` option (which find is missing)

Comment: Can you point me to where this is actually guaranteed? I couldn't find a `-b` option in POSIX-2017, nor could I find anything about mangling the output format. Quite the opposite, in the non-normative section, it explicitly says "As with many of the utilities that deal with filenames, the output of ls for multiple files or in one of the long listing formats must be used carefully on systems where filenames can contain embedded white space." Linux Standard Base 5.0 only adds some extended behaviors to `-l` and `-p` but doesn't say anything about `-b` or newlines either.

Comment: `-b` is probably just a GNU option that never made it into standards, but will generally always be available on Linux.